# Form inputs change based on Category selected

Tags: javascript, php, forms

***A little background:***
Ok, so I am making a webpage that you can post items on like OLX, Shop.com, Alibaba, etc...

***What I am struggling with:***
I want to create a form that changes based on selected categories like this:
user selects car category and the form changes to have the following inputs
miles, Doors, Color, model, etc.

If the user selects condos it should ask:
floors, Bathrooms, bedrooms, etc...

My lang:

> **Php, Js***

My Db:

> **Mysql**

Categories are from a DB table that looks like this

```
ID | cat_name | cat_parent |
1  |Autos     |0           |
2  |Cars      |1           |
```

If I need to improve my Q please comment on what I should change, thx :)

Comment: Can you add the code you've tried so far, and what the problem is with it?

Comment: Gert B. i don't have code i am not sure how to build this system thats why i am asking someone to give me some guidance on where to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create one form for every category and save them in forms folder, then use require to include what type of form you need

```php
    <?php

         $curr_cat = "Autos"; // or Cars or Condo ...
         require "/forms/" . $cur_cat . ".html";

    ?>
```

Comment: okay wow i didn't think of that thx bud :)

Comment: happy to help 

Comment: hey, @Akbar Odilov can you maybe help me on how the database layout would look like? considering that there are different fields :)